# What the difference between exitthread and exitthreadcore in the applicationContext?

Tags: winforms

which one to use to actually close the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a slamdunk.  ExitThreadCore is a protected method of the ApplicationContext class.  You cannot call it directly, other than calling ExitThread.  Unless you override the class.  Not so sure why you'd want to do that, you haven't given a good reason to do so.

Use ApplicationContext.ExitThread.  Or Application.ExitThread.  Or just close you main window, it's all the same.